# Android Edittext : setOnFocusChangeListener doesn't work

Tags: java, android, android-edittext

i'm using this code for checking my edittext focus or not :

```
 gelar_pp=(EditText)polis.findViewById(R.id.gelar_pp);
    gelar_pp.setOnFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener() {
    LinearLayout layout_nama_pp=(LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.layout_nama_pp);
        public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
            if(!hasFocus){
                layout_nama_pp.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.border_corner_baris1);
            }else {
                layout_nama_pp.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.border_corner_baris1_klik);
            }
        } });
    ibu_pp=(EditText)polis.findViewById(R.id.ibu_pp);
    ibu_pp.setOnFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener() {
    LinearLayout layout_nama_pp=(LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.layout_nama_pp);
        public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
            if(!hasFocus){
                layout_nama_pp.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.border_corner_baris1);
            }else {
                layout_nama_pp.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.border_corner_baris1_klik);
            }
        } });
    edit_bukti_lain_pp=(EditText)polis.findViewById(R.id.edit_bukti_lain_pp);
    edit_bukti_lain_pp.setOnFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener() {
    LinearLayout layout_nama_pp=(LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.layout_nama_pp);
        public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
            if(!hasFocus){
                layout_nama_pp.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.border_corner_baris1);
            }else {
                layout_nama_pp.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.border_corner_baris1_klik);
            }
        } });
```

when i make simple my code, and change into :

```
    gelar_pp.setOnFocusChangeListener(listener);
ibu_pp.setOnFocusChangeListener(listener);
edit_bukti_lain_pp.setOnFocusChangeListener(listener);
        listener= new OnFocusChangeListener() {    
            LinearLayout layout_nama_pp=(LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.layout_nama_pp);
            public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
                if(!hasFocus){
                    layout_nama_pp.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.border_corner_baris1);
                }else {
                    layout_nama_pp.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.border_corner_baris1_klik);
                }
            }
        };
```

my code is not working, nothing change. is there any wrong with my code?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First initialize the listener and then set to EditTexts like

```
listener= new OnFocusChangeListener() {    
        LinearLayout layout_nama_pp=(LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.layout_nama_pp);
        public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
            if(!hasFocus){
                layout_nama_pp.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.border_corner_baris1);
            }else {
                layout_nama_pp.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.border_corner_baris1_klik);
            }
        }
    };
gelar_pp.setOnFocusChangeListener(listener);
ibu_pp.setOnFocusChangeListener(listener);
edit_bukti_lain_pp.setOnFocusChangeListener(listener);
```

and set focusable property to `true` for EditTexts if not set previously like...

```
editText.setFocusable(true);
```

Comment: Thank you... it's something that i've missed

Comment: You look like you know how to user `onFocusChangeListener` can you please help me out with the question I posted here? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38341339/cancelling-event-due-to-no-window-focus-motionevent

Comment: @ahitt6345:- Answered your question, please check and let me know if it doesn't work

Answer (score 9):

Add in XML

```
android:focusable="true"
android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
```

Comment: In my case, both had to be set true (Kotlin 1.4.31, SDK 30)

Answer (score 3):

Try like this

```
edit_Text.setOnFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener() {
@Override
public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
    if(hasFocus){
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "on focus", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }else {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "lost focus", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
   }
});
```